# Find the most common digit in a vector of integers

Tags: r

I am doing this practice problem that wants me to write a function that can calculate the digits that occur the most number of times in the array.

The example is input:

```
x = c(25, 2, 3, 57, 38, 41)
```

and the return value is 2, 3, 5, since these numbers 2, 3 and 5 all occurs 2 times which is the most.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would look something like this, although I am sure there are more efficient approaches:

```
my_vector <- c(25, 2, 3, 57, 38, 41)

# function to evaluate the number of times a certain digit occurrs
digit_occurrence <- function(vector) {
  
  # collape vector to a single string without commas
  x <- paste(vector, sep = '', collapse = '')

  # create empty vector
  digit <- c()

  # loop over each unique digit and store its occurrence
  for(i in paste(as.character(0:9))) {
    digit[i] <- lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr(i, x)))
  }

  digit

}
```

```
> digit_occurrence(my_vector)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 2 1 2 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems efficient enough than convert it to string then convert it back to numbers.

Comment: If you really only want the function to return the digit(s) in `my_vector` that occur most, just replace the `digit` object after the `for` loop by `names(digit[digit == max(digit)])`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `table()` function to get a dataframe with the frequency of each digit (instead of counting with a for loop), and then arranging that dataframe by frequency and extracting the top three digits directly:

```
input_vector <- c(25, 2, 3, 57, 38, 41)

top_digits <- function(my_array, n=3) {
  
  # `as.character` converts the digits to strings, 
  # `strsplit` splits each one into individual characters (e.g. "23" into "2" and "3")
  # and `unlist` "flattens" the result to a unique string vector 
  my_array_splitted <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(input_vector), ""))
  
  # `table` creates a vector of frequencies
  # `as.data.frame` converts the vector into a DF with 2 columns: digits and frequencies
  df_digits <- as.data.frame(table(my_array_splitted))
  
  # Sorting the DF by frequency
  df_digits <- df_digits[order(df_digits$Freq, decreasing = TRUE),]
  
  # Extracting the first `n` elements of the digits column (which is now sorted) and converting back to integer
  # (we need the intermediate step as character because the column is originally factor, and converting directly to integer is unsafe
  as.integer(as.character(df_digits$my_array_splitted[1:n]))
}
```

Comment: I think you need to make the first function argument ``input_vector``

Comment: @user438383 It's not needed, because the name of the argument when declaring the function is just meant to be used inside the function. BUT the example is missing calling the function: `top_digits(input_vector)`. That is going to return the top 3 digits of the input

Answer (score 1):

This approach is similar and uses `table`

```
count = function(x) {
    # make a table of counts of all the digits
    tab = table(strsplit(paste(x, collapse=""), ""))
    # access the names of the last digits
    names(tab[max(tab)])
}
```

And a fun benchmark because it's Christmas:

```
x = sample(1:1000, 100000, replace=T)

Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
               me(x)  46.63262  52.34020  57.33796  53.87266  58.91561 123.5481
             anou(x) 319.14199 351.43877 381.35371 374.78037 408.67354 490.3464
 digit_occurrence(x) 149.83663 151.61908 160.47220 156.88108 161.57646 245.5067
       top_digits(x)  42.40598  49.92426  55.87991  51.90813  56.61563 109.5608
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another option for you:

```
fn <- function(x) {
  # First We separate every single digit in each element but we need to turn
  # the each element into character string beforehand. We then use do.call 
  # function to apply c function on every element of the resulting list to 
  # flatten the list to a vector
  digits <- do.call(c, sapply(x, function(y) strsplit(as.character(y), "")))
  
  # In the end we calculate the frequencies and sort the in decreasing order
  most_freq <- sort(table(digits), decreasing = TRUE)
  most_freq
}

fn(x)

digits_num
2 3 5 1 4 7 8 
2 2 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: This was the way that I thought of after I posted the question here. Convert the numeric value into string, separate them, then convert them back to numeric value, then find the frequency. But it wasn't very efficient. The problem requires it has execution time <= 5 secs.

Comment: If that's the case you can omit the transforming back to numeric part, the code will still run.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to convert your numeric vector into a character vector, split the entire string and then make a frequency table:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ""))) -> t

# 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 
# 1 2 2 1 2 1 1
```

If you want to extract the numbers with highest frequency:

```
as.integer(names(t[t == which.max(t)])) 
#2 3 5
```